# MySQL SUM left join show all categories even with the sum of 0

Tags: mysql, sum, left-join

I wish to select all categories based on the sum of scores of a set of data, even if the set of data does not include the categories. However, it always only display categories with actual data no matter what I try.

I have created the following SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52a127/3

For ease of view, I'll paste the `select` statement here:

```
SELECT categories.id, IFNULL(SUM(raw_data.score), 0) as total
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN raw_data ON categories.id = raw_data.category_id
WHERE
(raw_data.quarter = '2018Q2' OR !raw_data.quarter) AND
raw_data.broker_id = 2 
GROUP BY categories.id
ORDER BY total DESC
```

As you can see from the fiddle, it only displays 2 categories, but I wish to select all 6 and have 0 for those with no results.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move condition from `WHERE` to `ON` clause:

```
SELECT categories.id, IFNULL(SUM(raw_data.score), 0) as total
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN raw_data ON categories.id = raw_data.category_id
  AND (raw_data.quarter = '2018Q2' OR !raw_data.quarter) 
  AND raw_data.broker_id = 2 
GROUP BY categories.id
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52a127/4/0)**

Comment: @MikeFeng Some explainment: Because off the WHERE statement the MySQL optimizer is rewritting the SQL into a INNER JOIN instead off LEFT JOIN.. it's visible here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vfS4aGQ71xHdwWvhBrCmnn/0

Comment: You sir are a scholar.